# Wpf google Oauth2 not working when published

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, google-api

I made an application wich made use of the google drive API. To acces my google drive i needed to authenticate with the `OAuth2` API. Now while testing it all worked fine, never had a problem. But when i publish the application i dont get the popup in my browser.

I use Google Chrome on windows 10 x64

The way i did it:

```
 UserCredential credential;

             using (var stream =
                 new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
             {
                 string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                     System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                 credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                     GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                     Scopes,
                     "user",
                     CancellationToken.None,
                     new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                 Debug.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
             }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you sure the client_secret file is stored where you're looking for it?

Comment: does it change when u publish it then? i just put it in my project tree http://prntscr.com/b2cof0

Comment: to get the current path use Server.MapPath

Comment: It's a wpf application, so dont think Server.MapPath will work. I now used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory but for some reason client_secret.json isnt there while other resources i added are there

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't know why I thought it was an asp .net project, my bad. Try to check the "copy file to the output directory" on the context menu of the file on VS.